# Remove second line or the same number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server. And I used this code:

```
 select distinct A.CustomerNo, A.INV_Nr, B.Code, A.Price 
 from INVOICE A.
      INVOICE_LINE B
 where
      A.IVC_Nr = B.IVC_Nr
```

The output is like this:

```
| CustomerNo   |    INV_Nr   |   Code   | Price |
=================================================
| 1100021      |    500897   |   1404   | 2500  |
| 1100021      |    500897   |   1403   | 2500  |
| 1100022      |    500898   |   1405   | 3500  |
| 1100023      |    500899   |   1405   | 3000  |
| 1100023      |    500899   |   1403   | 3000  |
```

How can I remove the second line and get only the 1st line of the same number and should be like this:

```
| CustomerNo   |    INV_Nr   |   Code   | Price |
=================================================
| 1100021      |    500897   |   1404   | 2500  |
| 1100022      |    500898   |   1405   | 3500  |
| 1100023      |    500899   |   1405   | 3000  |
```

Thanks,

Comment: A word of warning - your "second line" is random. The order may change after an insert. If you want an order, put a defined ORDER BY into your select.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the problem was tag with `SQL Server 2005+`, you can use `Common Table Expression` and `Window Function` on this.

```
WITH recordsList
AS
(
    SELECT  A.CustomerNo, A.INV_Nr, B.Code, A.Price ,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.CustomerNo
                                ORDER BY B.Code DESC) rn
    FROM    INVOICE A
            INNER JOIN INVOICE_LINE B
                ON A.IVC_Nr = B.IVC_Nr
)
SELECT  CustomerNo, INV_Nr, Code, Price
FROM    recordsList
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with slight changes*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1f28/1)

Comment: `+1` I didn't know about common table expression.